# Want to know Partial view called by which action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

i'm working on asp.net MVC-4. i have a scenario that add or update has common view which is actually a partial view. now i want to ask that how do i know that i'm in added mode or update mode? Thanks in advance. if my question is not clear to you. i will try to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property to specify the Mode in the Model that you pass to that View.

```
public bool IsEditMode {get;set;}
```

So in the Controller you set this property on the Model depending on the mode, so it's available in the View.

Comment: How about this, if i decide it on the basis of action i called
`bool isEditMode = (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "AddressEdit")? true:false;`

Comment: I suggest creating a ViewModel and adding this property. Sure you can make it work with the ViewContext, but in my opinion the objects sent to the View should contain enough information to render the view.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a bad design choice to just add a property that has no added value to the model/class itself. Even when the property would not be mapped to the database. I would instead use the viewbag to differentiate between add/edit.

An even better solution would be by using ViewModels. You can have an EditViewModel.cs and AddViewModel.cs that are both implementing a common interface so that they can be passed to the same cshtml view.

This has the following advantages:

- it is more future proof when you want to have different properties for the add and edit model
- you are not operating directly on the model, but on a viewmodel, which is more secure
- in your controller it's easy to assert if (model is EditViewModel) or if (model is AddViewModel)

Kind regards